# URL to Post to Tumblr

Tags: php, url, oauth, tumblr

Like many others, I've been killing braincells trying to get oauth to work on MAMP. So instead, I went to my native language (python) and got my access token and access token secret for Tumblr in a jiffy. I still want to write something in php to post to tumblr, but I'm stuck on figuring out what the URL is that I need to be posting to.

I know the url is

https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/test.tumblr.com/post

What I'm stuck on is where I put the access tokens in the url. My guess was:

https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/test.tumblr.com/post?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_token_secret=XXX&access_token=XXX&access_token_secret=XXX

I've tried variations of that, but nothing really seemed to work. Perhaps this was a problem with the headers? Do I absolutely need to install the php oauth client and write something on that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes.

The parameters you are passing there are in the URL (`HTTP_GET`). They need to be in the `Authorization` header instead.

A typical `HTTP_GET` looks like:

```
GET /questions/12451564/url-to-post-to-tumblr?someval=something HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

A typical OAuth might look like:

```
GET /v2/blog/test.tumblr.com/post
Host: api.tumblr.com
Authorization: OAuth realm="Photos",
    oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",
    oauth_token="nnch734d00sl2jdk",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="137131202",
    oauth_nonce="chapoH",
    oauth_signature="MdpQcU8iPSUjWoN%2FUDMsK2sui9I%3D"
```

This is not the only request - there are calls to initialise a temporary token prior to this request as well hence the endpoints given in the [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth):

Example partially from [RFC for OAuth - 1.2 Example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-5)

Comment: Word, thanks. I'm gonna try use a different oauth library then.